How to transform columnar data with vertical repeated records into a a normal table format in excel
I am exporting data from an old system into excel, but data always comes vertically.
It comes from and old system where data is dumbed in a columnar form, hundreds of records coming in a single column, with the data of each records is repeated vertically.
but I need to transform it tot a table format. see attached image.screen shot showing the vertical data on left , and the desired format on left
